# The Contents of my String are Lost When I Pass it to Another Method as a Parameter?

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine, parameters

I am trying to create a Regular Expression system as part of my program. When I pass emailSub (which is a String version of an InputField for the user's email) into other functions within the program, the emailSub goes from the email address (e.g: emailaddress@emailprovider.com) to null (I know this because the output of a Debug.Log before being passed is the email address and Debug.Log-ing it after passing it comes back with " ". This means that when it reaches the length check (IsEmailValid) it is less than 6 characters so all email addresses are rejected as invalid.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
using System.Globalization; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using System;

public class RegEx : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField emailField;
    public Button acceptSubmissionButton;
    public string emailSub;

    public void Start()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        input.onEndEdit = se;
    }

    private void SubmitName(string arg0)
    {
        Debug.Log(arg0);
        emailSub = arg0;
        Debug.Log(emailSub);
    }

    public void Sequencer(string emailSub)
    {
        Debug.Log(emailSub);
        IsEmailValid(emailSub);
        Main(emailSub);
    }

    public static bool IsEmailValid(string emailSub)
    {
        if (emailSub.Length <= 6)
        {
            Debug.Log(emailSub + "1");
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailSub))
        {
            Debug.Log(emailSub + "2");
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            emailSub = Regex.Replace(emailSub, @"(@)(.+)$", DomainMapper, RegexOptions.None, 
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            string DomainMapper(Match match)
            {
                var idnConversion = new IdnMapping();
                var processDomainName = idnConversion.GetAscii(match.Groups[2].Value);
                Debug.Log(emailSub + "3");
                return match.Groups[1].Value + processDomainName;
            }
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            Debug.Log(emailSub + "4");
            return Regex.IsMatch(emailSub, @"^(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + @"(([0-9a-z][-0- 
            9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, 
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string emailSub)
    {
        if (RegEx.IsEmailValid(emailSub))
        {
            Debug.Log($"Valid:   {emailSub}");
            Debug.Log(emailSub + "5");
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"Invalid: {emailSub}");
            Debug.Log(emailSub + "6");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a field called `emailSub` which is not the same as the parameter used in several methods. You assign it to `arg0` in `SubmitName` and never use it anywhere else. Rename the field and then retest. If the same thing happens, the field is unnecessary. If something changes, the logic error will be less obscure due to confusing names.

Comment: Please be consistent with `return`s from code. Some of the `return`s in `IsEmailValid` are preceded by `Debug.Log(...)` and some are not. That makes it difficult to see what path the code takes. I have no idea whether this is hindering your understanding of your problem.

Comment: I suggest Don't use same name with a variable and argument (which is function's input). You used `public string emailSub;` and `public void Sequencer (string emailSub) `. Change one of them

Comment: I mean change `public string emailSub` with `public string email`. And you can see what is wrong in your code easily. Otherwise maybe name will shadowed.

Comment: when and how is `Sequencer` called? And **do not** call a method `public static void Main` ...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help. I fixed the problem by calling the other functions from within the SubmitName() function. The problem was that the functions were running before the SubmitName() had updated the contents of arg0.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to provide the answer, because that hides the original question. Instead you should write an answer to the question. As well as just providing the code it would be helpful if your answer explained both the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The answer below was written by the person who asked the original question, but they wrote it as a replacement of the question, not in answer.*

---

I fixed the problem, the program takes the contents of a text field and decides whether the text is in a valid email format or not. The problem was that the functions were running before the `SubmitName()` had updated the contents of `arg0`. Here is the working code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class RegEx : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField emailField;
    public Button acceptSubmissionButton;
    public string emailSub;

    public void Start()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        input.onEndEdit = se;
    }
    private void SubmitName(string arg0)
    {
        Debug.Log(arg0);
        IsEmailValid(arg0);
        ValidCheck(arg0);
    }

    public void Sequencer(string emailSub)
    {
        Debug.Log(emailSub);
        IsEmailValid(emailSub);
        ValidCheck(emailSub);
    }

    public static bool IsEmailValid(string arg0)
    {
        if (arg0.Length <= 6)
        {
            return false;

        }

        try
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(arg0, @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)); // The pattern is taken from an article written by Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void ValidCheck(string arg0)
    {
        if (IsEmailValid(arg0))
        {
            Debug.Log($"Valid:   {arg0}");
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"Invalid: {arg0}");
        }
    }
}
```